# Jquery Turbolink Ruby on Rails 4 Heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

My questions about roundabout.js in localhost its works normal  but when i push to heroku its not working. And on my app only this js not working.
I try to put page:load but not working maybe i do somthing wrong  
this is rounabout.js

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
**
 * jQuery Roundabout - v1.1
 * http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/
 *
 * Moves list-items of enabled ordered and unordered lists long
 * a chosen path. Includes the default "lazySusan" path, that
 * moves items long a spinning turntable.
 *
 * Terms of Use // jQuery Roundabout
 * 
 * Open source under the BSD license
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010, Fred LeBlanc
 * All rights reserved.
 * 
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without 
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 * 
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above 
 *     copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following 
 *     disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided 
 *     with the distribution.
 *   - Neither the name of the author nor the names of its contributors 
 *     may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this 
 *     software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" 
 * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE 
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE 
 * ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE 
 * LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR 
 * CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF 
 * SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS 
 * INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN 
 * CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) 
 * ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE 
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */


// creates a default shape to be used for pathing


jQuery.extend({
 roundabout_shape: {
  def: 'lazySusan',
  lazySusan: function(r, a, t) {
   return {
    x: Math.sin(r + a), 
    y: (Math.sin(r + 3*Math.PI/2 + a) / 8) * t, 
    z: (Math.cos(r + a) + 1) / 2,
    scale: (Math.sin(r + Math.PI/2 + a) / 2) + 0.5
   };
  }
 }
});

jQuery.fn.roundabout = function() {
 var options = (typeof arguments[0] != 'object') ? {} : arguments[0];

 // set options and fill in defaults
 options = {
  bearing: (typeof options.bearing == 'undefined') ? 0.0 : jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(options.bearing % 360.0),
  tilt: (typeof options.tilt == 'undefined') ? 0.0 : jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(options.tilt),
  minZ: (typeof options.minZ == 'undefined') ? 100 : parseInt(options.minZ, 10),
  maxZ: (typeof options.maxZ == 'undefined') ? 400 : parseInt(options.maxZ, 10),
  minOpacity: (typeof options.minOpacity == 'undefined') ? 0.40 : jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(options.minOpacity),
  maxOpacity: (typeof options.maxOpacity == 'undefined') ? 1.00 : jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(options.maxOpacity),
  minScale: (typeof options.minScale == 'undefined') ? 0.40 : jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(options.minScale),
  maxScale: (typeof options.maxScale == 'undefined') ? 1.00 : jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(options.maxScale),
  duration: (typeof options.duration == 'undefined') ? 600 : parseInt(options.duration, 10),
  btnNext: options.btnNext || null,
  btnPrev: options.btnPrev || null,
  easing: options.easing || 'swing',
  clickToFocus: (options.clickToFocus !== false),
  focusBearing: (typeof options.focusBearing == 'undefined') ? 0.0 : jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(options.focusBearing % 360.0),
  shape: options.shape || 'lazySusan',
  debug: options.debug || false,
  childSelector: options.childSelector || 'li',
  startingChild: (typeof options.startingChild == 'undefined') ? null : parseInt(options.startingChild, 10),
  reflect: (typeof options.reflect == 'undefined' || options.reflect === false) ? false : true
 };

 // assign things 
 this.each(function(i) {
  var ref = jQuery(this);
  var period = jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(360.0 / ref.children(options.childSelector).length);
  var startingBearing = (options.startingChild === null) ? options.bearing : options.startingChild * period;
  
  // set starting styles
  ref
   .addClass('roundabout-holder')
   .css('padding', 0)
   .css('position', 'relative')
   .css('z-index', options.minZ);
  
  // set starting options
  ref.data('roundabout', {
   'bearing': startingBearing,
   'tilt': options.tilt,
   'minZ': options.minZ,
   'maxZ': options.maxZ,
   'minOpacity': options.minOpacity,
   'maxOpacity': options.maxOpacity,
   'minScale': options.minScale,
   'maxScale': options.maxScale,
   'duration': options.duration,
   'easing': options.easing,
   'clickToFocus': options.clickToFocus,
   'focusBearing': options.focusBearing,
   'animating': 0,
   'childInFocus': -1,
   'shape': options.shape,
   'period': period,
   'debug': options.debug,
   'childSelector': options.childSelector,
   'reflect': options.reflect
  });
    
  // bind click events
  if (options.clickToFocus === true) {
   ref.children(options.childSelector).each(function(i) {
    jQuery(this).click(function(e) {
     var degrees = (options.reflect === true) ? 360.0 - (period * i) : period * i;
     degrees = jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(degrees);
     if (!jQuery.roundabout_isInFocus(ref, degrees)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (ref.data('roundabout').animating === 0) {
       ref.roundabout_animateAngleToFocus(degrees);
      }
      return false;
     }
    });
   });
  }
  
  // bind next buttons
  if (options.btnNext) {
   jQuery(options.btnNext).bind('click.roundabout', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (ref.data('roundabout').animating === 0) {
     ref.roundabout_animateToNextChild();
    }
    return false;
   });
  }
  
  // bind previous buttons
  if (options.btnPrev) {
   jQuery(options.btnPrev).bind('click.roundabout', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (ref.data('roundabout').animating === 0) {
     ref.roundabout_animateToPreviousChild();
    }
    return false;
   });
  }
 });

 // start children
 this.roundabout_startChildren();

 // callback once ready
 if (typeof arguments[1] === 'function') {
  var callback = arguments[1], ref = this;
  setTimeout(function() { callback(ref); }, 0);
 }

 return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_startChildren = function() {
 this.each(function(i) {
  var ref = jQuery(this);
  var data = ref.data('roundabout');
  var children = ref.children(data.childSelector);
  
  children.each(function(i) {
   var degrees = (data.reflect === true) ? 360.0 - (data.period * i) : data.period * i;

   // apply classes and css first
   jQuery(this)
    .addClass('roundabout-moveable-item')
    .css('position', 'absolute');
   
   // then measure
   jQuery(this).data('roundabout', {
    'startWidth': jQuery(this).width(),
    'startHeight': jQuery(this).height(),
    'startFontSize': parseInt(jQuery(this).css('font-size'), 10),
    'degrees': degrees
   });
  });
  
  ref.roundabout_updateChildPositions();
 });
 return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_setTilt = function(newTilt) {
 this.each(function(i) {
  jQuery(this).data('roundabout').tilt = newTilt;
  jQuery(this).roundabout_updateChildPositions();
 });
 
 if (typeof arguments[1] === 'function') {
  var callback = arguments[1], ref = this;
  setTimeout(function() { callback(ref); }, 0);
 }
 
 return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_setBearing = function(newBearing) {
 this.each(function(i) {
  jQuery(this).data('roundabout').bearing = jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(newBearing % 360, 2);
  jQuery(this).roundabout_updateChildPositions();
 });

 if (typeof arguments[1] === 'function') {
  var callback = arguments[1], ref = this;
  setTimeout(function() { callback(ref); }, 0);
 }
 
 return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_adjustBearing = function(delta) {
 delta = jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(delta);
 if (delta !== 0) {
  this.each(function(i) {
   jQuery(this).data('roundabout').bearing = jQuery.roundabout_getBearing(jQuery(this)) + delta;
   jQuery(this).roundabout_updateChildPositions();
  });
 }
 
 if (typeof arguments[1] === 'function') {
  var callback = arguments[1], ref = this;
  setTimeout(function() { callback(ref); }, 0);
 }

 return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_adjustTilt = function(delta) {
 delta = jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(delta);
 if (delta !== 0) {
  this.each(function(i) {
   jQuery(this).data('roundabout').tilt = jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(jQuery(this).roundabout_get('tilt') + delta);
   jQuery(this).roundabout_updateChildPositions();
  });
 }
 
 if (typeof arguments[1] === 'function') {
  var callback = arguments[1], ref = this;
  setTimeout(function() { callback(ref); }, 0);
 }

 return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_animateToBearing = function(bearing) {
 bearing = jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(bearing);
 var currentTime = new Date();
 var duration    = (typeof arguments[1] == 'undefined') ? null : arguments[1];
 var easingType  = (typeof arguments[2] == 'undefined') ? null : arguments[2];
 var passedData  = (typeof arguments[3] !== 'object')   ? null : arguments[3];

 this.each(function(i) {
  var ref = jQuery(this), data = ref.data('roundabout'), timer, easingFn, newBearing;
  var thisDuration = (duration === null) ? data.duration : duration;
  var thisEasingType = (easingType !== null) ? easingType : data.easing || 'swing';

  if (passedData === null) {
   passedData = {
    timerStart: currentTime,
    start: jQuery.roundabout_getBearing(ref),
    totalTime: thisDuration
   };
  }
  timer = currentTime - passedData.timerStart;

  if (timer < thisDuration) {
   data.animating = 1;
   
   if (typeof jQuery.easing.def == 'string') {
    easingFn = jQuery.easing[thisEasingType] || jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def];
    newBearing = easingFn(null, timer, passedData.start, bearing - passedData.start, passedData.totalTime);
   } else {
    newBearing = jQuery.easing[thisEasingType]((timer / passedData.totalTime), timer, passedData.start, bearing - passedData.start, passedData.totalTime);
   }
   
   ref.roundabout_setBearing(newBearing, function() { ref.roundabout_animateToBearing(bearing, thisDuration, thisEasingType, passedData); });
  } else {
   bearing = (bearing < 0) ? bearing + 360 : bearing % 360;
   data.animating = 0;
   ref.roundabout_setBearing(bearing);
  }
 }); 
 return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_animateToDelta = function(delta) {
 var duration = arguments[1], easing = arguments[2];
 this.each(function(i) {
  delta = jQuery.roundabout_getBearing(jQuery(this)) + jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(delta);
  jQuery(this).roundabout_animateToBearing(delta, duration, easing);
 });
 return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_animateToChild = function(childPos) { 
 var duration = arguments[1], easing = arguments[2]; 
 this.each(function(i) {
  var ref = jQuery(this), data = ref.data('roundabout');
  if (data.childInFocus !== childPos && data.animating === 0) {  
   var child = jQuery(ref.children(data.childSelector)[childPos]);
   ref.roundabout_animateAngleToFocus(child.data('roundabout').degrees, duration, easing);
  }
 });
 return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_animateToNearbyChild = function(passedArgs, which) {
 var duration = passedArgs[0], easing = passedArgs[1];
 this.each(function(i) {
  var data     = jQuery(this).data('roundabout');
  var bearing  = jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(360.0 - jQuery.roundabout_getBearing(jQuery(this)));
  var period   = data.period, j = 0, range;
  var reflect  = data.reflect;
  var length   = jQuery(this).children(data.childSelector).length;

  bearing = (reflect === true) ? bearing % 360.0 : bearing;
  
  if (data.animating === 0) {
   // if we're not reflecting and we're moving to next or
   //    we are reflecting and we're moving previous
   if ((reflect === false && which === 'next') || (reflect === true && which !== 'next')) {
    bearing = (bearing === 0) ? 360 : bearing;
       
    // counterclockwise
    while (true && j < length) {
     range = { lower: jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(period * j), upper: jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(period * (j + 1)) };
     range.upper = (j == length - 1) ? 360.0 : range.upper;  // adjust for javascript being bad at floats

     if (bearing <= range.upper && bearing > range.lower) {
      jQuery(this).roundabout_animateToDelta(bearing - range.lower, duration, easing);
      break;
     }
     j++;
    }
   } else {
    // clockwise
    while (true) {
     range = { lower: jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(period * j), upper: jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(period * (j + 1)) };
     range.upper = (j == length - 1) ? 360.0 : range.upper;  // adjust for javascript being bad at floats

     if (bearing >= range.lower && bearing < range.upper) {
      jQuery(this).roundabout_animateToDelta(bearing - range.upper, duration, easing);
      break;
     }
     j++;
    }
   }
  }
 });
 return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_animateToNextChild = function() { 
 return this.roundabout_animateToNearbyChild(arguments, 'next');
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_animateToPreviousChild = function() { 
 return this.roundabout_animateToNearbyChild(arguments, 'previous');
};

// moves a given angle to the focus by the shortest means possible
jQuery.fn.roundabout_animateAngleToFocus = function(target) {
 var duration = arguments[1], easing = arguments[2];
 this.each(function(i) {
  var delta = jQuery.roundabout_getBearing(jQuery(this)) - target;
  delta = (Math.abs(360.0 - delta) < Math.abs(0.0 - delta)) ? 360.0 - delta : 0.0 - delta;
  delta = (delta > 180) ? -(360.0 - delta) : delta;
  
  if (delta !== 0) {
   jQuery(this).roundabout_animateToDelta(delta, duration, easing); 
  }
 });
 return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_updateChildPositions = function() {
 this.each(function(i) {
  var ref = jQuery(this), data = ref.data('roundabout');
  var inFocus = -1;
  var info = {
   bearing: jQuery.roundabout_getBearing(ref),
   tilt: data.tilt,
   stage: { width: Math.floor(ref.width() * 0.9), height: Math.floor(ref.height() * 0.9) },
   animating: data.animating,
   inFocus: data.childInFocus,
   focusBearingRad: jQuery.roundabout_degToRad(data.focusBearing),
   shape: jQuery.roundabout_shape[data.shape] || jQuery.roundabout_shape[jQuery.roundabout_shape.def]
  };
  info.midStage = { width: info.stage.width / 2, height: info.stage.height / 2 };
  info.nudge = { width: info.midStage.width + info.stage.width * 0.05, height: info.midStage.height + info.stage.height * 0.05 };
  info.zValues = { min: data.minZ, max: data.maxZ, diff: data.maxZ - data.minZ };
  info.opacity = { min: data.minOpacity, max: data.maxOpacity, diff: data.maxOpacity - data.minOpacity };
  info.scale = { min: data.minScale, max: data.maxScale, diff: data.maxScale - data.minScale };

  // update child positions
  ref.children(data.childSelector).each(function(i) {
   if (jQuery.roundabout_updateChildPosition(jQuery(this), ref, info, i) && info.animating === 0) {
    inFocus = i;
    jQuery(this).addClass('roundabout-in-focus');
   } else {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('roundabout-in-focus');
   }
  });

  // update status of who is in focus
  if (inFocus !== info.inFocus) {
   jQuery.roundabout_triggerEvent(ref, info.inFocus, 'blur');

   if (inFocus !== -1) {
    jQuery.roundabout_triggerEvent(ref, inFocus, 'focus');
   }

   data.childInFocus = inFocus;
  }
 }); 
 return this; 
};

//----------------

jQuery.roundabout_getBearing = function(el) {
 return jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(el.data('roundabout').bearing) % 360;
};

jQuery.roundabout_degToRad = function(degrees) {
 return (degrees % 360.0) * Math.PI / 180.0;
};

jQuery.roundabout_isInFocus = function(el, target) {
 return (jQuery.roundabout_getBearing(el) % 360 === (target % 360));
};

jQuery.roundabout_triggerEvent = function(el, child, eventType) {
 return (child < 0) ? this : jQuery(el.children(el.data('roundabout').childSelector)[child]).trigger(eventType);
};

jQuery.roundabout_toFloat = function(number) {
 number = Math.round(parseFloat(number) * 1000) / 1000;
 return parseFloat(number.toFixed(2));
};

jQuery.roundabout_updateChildPosition = function(child, container, info, childPos) {
 var ref = jQuery(child), data = ref.data('roundabout'), out = [];
 var rad = jQuery.roundabout_degToRad((360.0 - ref.data('roundabout').degrees) + info.bearing);
 
 // adjust radians to be between 0 and Math.PI * 2
 while (rad < 0) {
  rad = rad + Math.PI * 2;
 }
 while (rad > Math.PI * 2) {
  rad = rad - Math.PI * 2;
 }
 
 var factors = info.shape(rad, info.focusBearingRad, info.tilt); // obj with x, y, z, and scale values

 // correct
 factors.scale = (factors.scale > 1) ? 1 : factors.scale;
 factors.adjustedScale = (info.scale.min + (info.scale.diff * factors.scale)).toFixed(4);
 factors.width = (factors.adjustedScale * data.startWidth).toFixed(4);
 factors.height = (factors.adjustedScale * data.startHeight).toFixed(4);
 
 // alter item
 ref
  .css('left', ((factors.x * info.midStage.width + info.nudge.width) - factors.width / 2.0).toFixed(1) + 'px')
  .css('top', ((factors.y * info.midStage.height + info.nudge.height) - factors.height / 2.0).toFixed(1) + 'px')
  .css('width', factors.width + 'px')
  .css('height', factors.height + 'px')
  .css('opacity', (info.opacity.min + (info.opacity.diff * factors.scale)).toFixed(2))
  .css('z-index', Math.round(info.zValues.min + (info.zValues.diff * factors.z)))
  .css('font-size', (factors.adjustedScale * data.startFontSize).toFixed(2) + 'px')
  .attr('current-scale', factors.adjustedScale);
 
 if (container.data('roundabout').debug === true) {
  out.push('<div style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 10px; padding: 2px; width: ' + ref.css('width') + '; background-color: #ffc;">');
  out.push('<strong style="font-size: 12px; white-space: nowrap;">Child ' + childPos + '</strong><br />');
  out.push('<strong>left:</strong> ' + ref.css('left') + '<br /><strong>top:</strong> ' + ref.css('top') + '<br />');
  out.push('<strong>width:</strong> ' + ref.css('width') + '<br /><strong>opacity:</strong> ' + ref.css('opacity') + '<br />');
  out.push('<strong>z-index:</strong> ' + ref.css('z-index') + '<br /><strong>font-size:</strong> ' + ref.css('font-size') + '<br />');
  out.push('<strong>scale:</strong> ' + ref.attr('current-scale'));
  out.push('</div>');
  
  ref.html(out.join(''));
 }

 return jQuery.roundabout_isInFocus(container, ref.data('roundabout').degrees);
};
```

production.rb

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.css_compressor = :yui
end
```

Gemfile

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
source 'https://rubygems.org'



gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'


gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'fabricjs-rails', '~> 2.0'
gem 'rolify', :git => 'git://github.com/EppO/rolify.git'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'puma'
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:x64_mingw, :mingw, :mswin, :jruby]
```

aplication.js

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require cufon-yui
//= require cufon-replace
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

and gallery_init.js

```html
$(document).on('page:change', function() {
 $('#myRoundabout').roundabout({
   shape: 'figure8',
   minOpacity: 1
 });
});
```

i try any other configuration but on heroku its not working on localhost i dont have any problem

Comment: and on my page in devkit chrome in script i have / jQuery(...).roundabout is not a function

Comment: i have found when i add //= require roundabout to my application.js i have the same error on localhost  jQuery(...).roundabout is not a function so i think this is a problem i dont know how to repaire this error

Comment: i have 2 js in me apps and from there is some problem i have tride add jQuery.noConflict(); to roundabout.js